# Dynamically exploring and extracting specific field from a JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, react-query

I am retrieving some data using `react_query`, returning the data as:

```
return fetch(getRequest).then((response) => response.json())
```

Later I turn the data into Arrays as follows.

```
Query.data.map(({field1,field2,field3,}) => [field1, field2,field3])
```

To be honest, I am not sure if it is the best approach, as it returns an `[Array(3), Array(3), Array(3) ...]` object instead of a maybe better `field1:[...], field2:[...], field3:[...]` kind of dictionary.

Anyway, either playing with the format or the data, I want to extract a given field dynamically. I get the name of thee field I want to extract in a string format.

The main problem I have is that I can´t just apply this string to do something like

```
let field_to_call = "example"
Query.data.map(({field_to_call}) => [field_to_call])
```

And that is because this code format needs the variable itself an not some string reference. What is the best approach for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the values from your data that belong to a specific property, you can just access that property in the callback function:

```js
const data = [
    {field1: "a", field2: "B", field3: 13},
    {field1: "c", field2: "D", field3: 26},
    {field1: "e", field2: "E", field3: 39},
];

let field_to_call = "field2"
const result = data.map(obj => obj[field_to_call]); 

console.log(result);
```

Or, if you want to use destructuring, use the computed property name syntax:

```js
const data = [
    {field1: "a", field2: "B", field3: 13},
    {field1: "c", field2: "D", field3: 26},
    {field1: "e", field2: "E", field3: 39},
];

let field_to_call = "field2"
const result = data.map(({[field_to_call]: value}) => value); 

console.log(result);
```